# How do text rendering engines combine lowercase "g" with a cedilla " ̧ " to get "ģ"?

Tags: glyphs, unicode, ttf

To be clear, I'm not wondering about how diacritics are combined in general, I want to know *specifically* about this case. In the font files I've inspected, the cedilla glyph is always stored as the bottom-attached mark that you typically see in other letters (Ģ, ķ, etc.) and the unicode standard has it classified as a bottom-attached mark. Yet, when combined with a lowercase "g" it is rendered above the base character and has a different shape. At first, I assumed that this was a ligature substitution, but I can't find this case in the ligature substitution tables in any font files I've looked at.

My only remaining thoughts are that either there's some table in the font file that I'm not familiar with coming into play here, or the text rendering engine is normalizing the sequence to a single "equivalent" character before rendering. If it's the latter, then the notion that the character is "equivalent" seems incorrect.

Any further insight into this would be helpful. I'm sure there are other examples of this, but this is the first one I found that has me scratching my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not so much my own answer but rather what I have managed to find by doing some searching. I'm almost sure there's probably something wrong with it though.

1. This doesn't seem to have anything to do with text rendering engines. It looks like these diacritics are combined in fonts themselves, inside the U+0122 Ģ and U+0123 ģ characters. I'm not exactly sure how it's done. But opening up a font like Noto Sans Regular in FontForge, I can clearly see that U+0123 is a letter g combined with a "commaaccentrotate".  And U+0122 is a G combined with "commaaccent2".

Here's U+0123 ģ opened in FontForge

[image]

2. The [Wikipedia page on Cedilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cedilla) claims that the "cedilla" on these letters has been misnamed in the Unicode standard, and is actually an ***ogonek***.  I can't verify this, but here is what it says:

> *This diacritic is not to be confused with the ogonek (◌̨), which
> resembles the cedilla but mirrored. It looks also very similar to the
> diacrital comma, which is used in the Romanian and Latvian alphabets,
> and which is misnamed 'cedilla' in the Unicode standard.*

Anyway, here are some examples showing the glyphs for the upper and lowercase glyphs. As you can see, Verdana seems substantially different from the others. So I suppose ultimately it depends on how the font designer made them.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response! So, you're thinking that there's some pre-processing happening before the text renderer that's replacing the two-character sequence LATIN SMALL LETTER G (U+0067) + CEDILLA (U+00B8) with the single character LATIN SMALL LETTER G WITH CEDILLA (U+0123)?

Comment: @sgfw Yes. Looks like it's precombined inside the font itself.  I'm no font design expert though, so don't just take my word for it.

Comment: Found this article which explains it in more detail [Design with FontForge](http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/Diacritics_and_Accents.html). Apparently the software has basic automated placement of the diacritics, or more precise manual placement using anchor points. But as I said, I'm no expert in designing fonts.